# The limit of $\frac{{{n + d - 1} \choose d}}{n^d} $ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

could someone check if my computation of the limit of $\frac{{{n + d - 1} \choose d}}{n^d}$ as $n \to \infty$ is correct?

I used simple reasoning to come up with that the limit is zero but it feels wrong.

$\frac{{{n + d - 1} \choose d}}{n^d}$
$\frac{(n+d-1)!}{d!(n+d-1-d)!} = \frac{(n+d-1) \dots n(n-1)}{d!} = 1 $ as $n\to \infty$
and then over $n^d$ gives me $0$.

Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $d=2$ and see, where it goes wrong. Then $(n^2+n)/(2n^2)$ does not tend to $1$. Also, compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199671/what-is-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnd-nd-choose-d) and others here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Apologies, I made a huge typo! the limit as $d \to \infty$ not n!

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I am sure, this is something I am trying to compute for myself because I am wondering about a runtime comparison its not from an exercise.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think since there is an answer already I may just edit this one back and ask again? I feel very bad for you and the other answerer.

Comment: I don't know, your original equation is a more or less a duplicate and has been solved there. It is $1/d!$ for the limit of the reciprocal, hence $d!$ for your case. The present question, for $n=2$ gives limit $0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Apologies, I can not post the question with d again as it flags duplicate with this one.
So is my original calculation correct for the case as n is constant and $ d \to \infty$?

Comment: As I said, take $n=2$ and $d\to \infty$. What do you get? $(d+1)/2^d$ for $d\to \infty$?

Comment: 0, thanks. Its just so surprising, thanks a lot! I also thought that the numerator just goes to 1 as n doesn't matter anymore the larger d gets. But again I was comparing two algorithms and didn't expect this result. (the former being faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(d) = n^{-d} \binom{n+d-1}{d}$.  Then $$f(d) = \frac{(n+d-1)!}{d!(n-1)!n^d} = \prod_{k=1}^d \frac{n+k-1}{nk} = \prod_{k=1}^d \left( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{nk} \right).$$  Since this product has a finite number of factors for a fixed $d$, as $n \to \infty$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(d) = \prod_{k=1}^d \left(\frac{1}{k} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k-1}{nk} \right) = \prod_{k=1}^d \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{d!}.$$

---

If you want the limit as $d \to \infty$, this is a different question.  You have for a fixed $n$

$$f(d) = \frac{1}{n^d} \prod_{m=1}^{n-1} \left(1 + \frac{d}{m}\right).$$
The product part of $f(d)$ is a polynomial, say $P(d)$, of degree $n-1$.  However, $n^d$ is exponential in $d$.  Since $d^n < n^d$ for $n > 1$ and $d$ sufficiently large, it follows that $f(d) \to 0$ as $d \to \infty$.  More formally, we can bound the product by noting $1 + d/m \le 1 + d$ for all $m \ge 1$:

$$f(d) \le \frac{1}{n^d} (1 + d)^{n-1}$$

and now the limiting behavior is obvious.

Comment: I am sooo sorry! I made a huge typo! I was looking for the limit as $d \to \infty$ not $n$

Comment: thank you so much. I am so happy!

Answer (score 1):

You drop the $n^d$ term and the quantity $(n+d-1) \dots n(n-1)$ should be $(n+d-1) \dots n$

In terms of doing the limit, first note that $$\binom{n+d-1}{d} = \frac{1}{d!}\prod_{i=0}^{d-1}(n+i)$$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{n+d-1}{d}}{n^d}&=\frac{1}{d!}\prod_{i=0}^{d-1}\frac{n+i}{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{d!}\prod_{i=0}^{d-1}\left( 1+\frac{i}{n}\right)
\end{align*}

Since the product is finite and for each $i$, $1+\frac{i}{n}$ goes to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the limit is $\frac{1}{d!}$

Comment: Why do you say that $(n + d - 1 - d)!$ should be $(n + d + 1 - d)!$?

Comment: Oh you're right. I will fix

Answer (score 0):

Using the gamma function
$$\binom{d+n-1}{d}=\frac{\Gamma (n+d)}{\Gamma (d+1) \Gamma (n)}=\frac 1{d!}\frac{\Gamma (n+d)}{ \Gamma (n)} $$ Now,use twice Stirling approximation
$$\frac{\Gamma (n+d)}{\Gamma (n)}=n^d\Bigg[1+\frac{d(d-1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \Bigg]$$